# JPA Cascade delete fail after persist

Tags: jpa

I use JPA for a classic relationship between two tables (1: N) :

RefCollectivite (1) ==> (N) ColPlanCompteM61

I want a cascade delete when a RefCollectivite entity is deleted.
The cascade delete works well, except when a RefCollectivite entity has just been created (When I create 1 RefCollectivite, I also create 232 ColPlanCompteM61).
ColPlanCompteM61 entities are not detected when RefCollectivite is deleted and the deletion fails because the foreign key is violated.

My code for persist RefCollectivite :

```
    public void creerRefCollectivite(RefCollectivite collectivite) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(collectivite);
        getEntityManager().flush(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Persist ColPlanCompteM61 :

```
public void initialiserCollectivite(RefCollectivite collectivite) {

    List<RefPlanCompteM61> listeRefPlanCompteM61 = getRefPlanCompteM61Facade().rechercherListeRefPlanCompteM61();

    for (RefPlanCompteM61 ligne : listeRefPlanCompteM61) {

        ColPlanCompteM61 colPlanCompteM61 = new ColPlanCompteM61(ligne, collectivite);

        try {
            getEntityManager().persist(colPlanCompteM61);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

My code for remove :

```
    public void supprimerRefCollectivite(RefCollectivite collectivite) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().remove(rechercherRefCollectivite(collectivite));
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
    }
}

    public RefCollectivite rechercherRefCollectivite(RefCollectivite collectivite) {  

    Query jQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery("select x from RefCollectivite x where x.idPk = :clePrimaire");

    jQuery.setParameter("clePrimaire", collectivite.getIdPk());

    try {
        return (RefCollectivite) jQuery.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Entity : RefCollectivite

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "RefCollectivite")
public class RefCollectivite implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="refCollectivite")
private List<ColPlanCompteM61> listePlanCompteM61;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idPk;
```

Entity : ColPlanCompteM61 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ColPlanCompteM61")
public class ColPlanCompteM61 implements Serializable{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REFCOLLECTIVITEFK", referencedColumnName = "IDPK", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private RefCollectivite refCollectivite;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idPk;
private int refCollectiviteFk;
private int refPlanCompteM61Fk;
private Double valeur01;
private Double valeur02;
private Double valeur03;
private Double valeur04;
private Double valeur05;
```

Comment: Can you share your entity design also? Also please share the methos which depicts the sequence of your inserts and deletions

Comment: I added the entitiy design in my post above

Comment: As per my understanding you would be invoking creerRefCollectivite method before initialiserCollectivite. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Try         getEntityManager().flush();  after persisting the list of RefPlanCompteM61

Comment: Does it work if you remove `insertable = false, updatable = false` (and declare them on the `refCollectiviteFk` column instead)? Why would you even map the join column in `ColPlanCompteM61`?

Comment: I do not know JPA well. Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

To cascade deletion of entities in a "[more aggressive remove cascading mode](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_)" you could add a `orphanRemoval=true` attribute to your relationship annotation in `RefCollectivite`. But also, please add some information about your RefCollectivite an its JPA design (Relationships).

Comment: I added the entitiy design in my post above

Comment: You could give it a try to use: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="refCollectivite",orphanRemoval=true)` inside `RefCollectivite`

Comment: which JPA version are you using?

Comment: JPA version 2.1